# Import in Magento Products from 2.1.5 to magento 2.3.4

Tags: import, import-products

I get the below error in log file

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getFrontendInput() on boolean in vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product.php:2626
Stack trace:
#0 vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product.php(2561): Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product->parseAttributesWithWrappedValues('color="Flame",f...')
#1 vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product.php(2541): Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product->getAdditionalAttributes('color="Flame",f...')
#2 vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product.php(2715): Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product->_parseAdditionalAttributes(Array)
#3 vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product.php(2748): Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product->_customFieldsMapping(Array)
#4 vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product.php on line 2626
```

Comment: `retrieveAttributeByCode()` obviously returns a boolean for at least one `$attributeCode`. I’d start by looking at which attribute code that is and continue debugging why `$this->getResource()->getAttribute($attributeCode)` returns a boolean for that attribute. Very likely the attribute simply doesn’t exist since `Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity::getAttribute()` will return the observed boolean `false` in that case, see comment in line 411.

Comment: I am new in magento2, I have a lot of products which need to import with their attributes, could you tell me how to investigate the issue to make the process done. How I can get the attribute which cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The new installation probably lacks an attribute you’re trying to import.

Add sth like `if(is_bool($attribute)){echo ‘Missing attribute: ‘.$attributeCode;}` right after line 2625 in order to identify the culprits.

Comment: Thanks, I added the code, but where I can find the print, and how the system will print the attributes however there is no products samples on the new updated magento installation.

Comment: Just watch the console output after you started the import from your terminal. You can also save the output to a file or email it to yourself instead of echo’ing it just to name a few possibilities. I don’t understand your second question but let’s start with the unknown attributes.